# how to verify object properties while write unit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, dbunit

```
    private Long itemId;

    private String longName;

    private String shortName;

    private String itemUrl;

    private Integer itemCount;

    private Long parentCategory;

    private Long childCategory;

    private Integer shopType;

    private Integer payPostage;

    private Long originalPrice;

    private String picUrl;

    private Long activityPrice;

    private String city;

    private String itemDesc;

    private Integer itemStatus;

    private String itemGuarantee;

    private Double discount;

    private String checkComment;

    private Long platformId;

    private Long sellerId;

    private String sellerNick;

    private Integer sellerCredit;

    private Long categoryId;

    private Long operatorId;

    private String operatorNick;

    private String sellerEmail;

    private String sellerPhone;

    private String sellerAddress;

    private String sellerShopUrl;

    private String sellerRealName;

    private String picUrlFromIC;

    private Integer itemType;

    private Integer tgType;

    private String attributes;

    private Integer isAuth = 0;

    private String[] itemCities;

    private Integer isBlack = 0;

    private double lowestPirce;

    private transient int pollNum;

    private Integer limitNum;
```

That is the object i have.
When i test a select operation(select the object from mysql). 

**should i verify each property of this object??** 

what is the best way to test such data access operations(I am using dbunit currently)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should i verify each property of this object?

Yes, you should. Otherwise, you would partially verify the state of the object, potentially resulting in unspecified data for the the unverified properties.

> What is the best way to test such data access operations(I am using dbunit currently)

Assert for equality of the actual dataset/table contents and the pre-determined dataset/table contents. This is covered in the [how-to guide of DbUnit](http://www.dbunit.org/howto.html#assertdata). This would make sense for mutating operations involving `INSERT`, `DELETE` or an `UPDATE`.

For `SELECT` operations, you can assert the values in the actual object and an expected object, or read the properties of the object into a Map, and compare it against the expected Map. If you've implemented `equals()` (and `hashcode()`) to consider all object properties, `assertEquals()` should be sufficient for verifying objects for equality. If you haven't implemented `equals()` to consider all the object's properties for equality, you can use the `assertThat()` method instead, with a custom matcher to verify if the object properties are equal.

Additionally, if you have multiple such tests that have a known set of inputs for an DAO operation and expected dataset/table contents after the DAO operation, you can consider [parameterizing the tests](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html), so that the test sequence is defined only once, but the test is executed multiple times with different inputs, and the system is asserted with different expected outputs.

Comment: Sounds good advice. I have learned the way to assert the real database content and the predefined one. but for select operations, compare the database and predefined dataset have no sense. I had to verify the object manually.    some column like timestamp are difficult to verify

Comment: Yes, it wouldn't make sense for SELECTs. I've edited my answer to account for that scenario.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. See this example, Item item = selectUserFromDB(); assert(item....) no object expected to assert. Shall I create a new one just for assert????

Comment: Yes, if you are using DbUnit to put the database into a known state before the test, then the returned object must contain a representation of that state. You would find it useful to create the expected result object first, then create a `DefaultDataSet` instance that can be used to load data with the expected result; when verifying the result, you can assert against the original object. You can refer to the test classes in `org.dbunit.operation` to figure out how to use the `DefaultDataSet` class; the package has tests for mutating operations, but you can extend the approach to SELECTs.

Answer (score 1):

`assertEquals` on the expected object and retrieved object should work I suppose. (I think this requires you overriding `equals` method appropriately).

Comment: I define the database record in dataset(dbunit), and it is not that easy to create object from the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

It can be beneficial to test select operation from the database especially if there is some orm or complicated select queries involved.

I believe your main concern is to make sure that when you change this class it won't break your unit tests if database mapping is still fine. You could implement very generic field comparison mechanism (like a custom equals method on all fields) or use some existing one - like [EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/EqualsBuilder.html) from Apache Commons.

Answer (score 0):

If you feel there is a risk of forgetting to load one of the attributes, or substituting two of these attributes, then definitely test it.

If you think it'll never happen, don't test it, and wait for a bug to happen. If it happens, introduce a unit-test which fails due to this bug, fix the bug, and verify that the unit-test doesn't fail anymore.

In short: there is no absolute rule, and it's up to you to decide